# Matching and replacing pattern delete the next paragraph

Tags: r

My text :

```
    text <- "
    justo pretium mollis fermentum, quam diam blandit lorem, et pulvinar neque lectus pharetra nunc. Quisque volutpat malesuada tempus. Praesent sagittis commodo ex, sed vulputate odio malesuada et. Praesent neque odio, posuere at egestas quis, convallis ut urna. Nunc venenatis aliquet turpis, at mattis diam dictum sit amet.
                                                            news·20000304·LF·172821401

    Sed luctus rutrum tortor sit amet placerat. Proin tempor faucibus erat, at scelerisque mauris."
```

I want to match and replace the `news·20000304·LF·172821401`line.

`news·20000304·LF·172821401`can change : `news·20050202·LF·20050202×2fig0102` or `news·20041129·LC·0041129lc_inx023` for example. In fact `news` and anything else with `·` characters.

What I tried :

```
    clean <- ("news·.+")

    text2 <- gsub(clean, "---\n",text) 
    cat(text2)
```

My result : the second paragraph is deleted.

What I want :

```
justo pretium mollis fermentum, quam diam blandit lorem, et pulvinar neque lectus pharetra nunc. 
Quisque volutpat malesuada tempus. Praesent sagittis commodo ex, sed vulputate odio malesuada et. 
Praesent neque odio, posuere at egestas quis, convallis ut urna. Nunc venenatis aliquet turpis, at mattis diam dictum sit amet.
---
Sed luctus rutrum tortor sit amet placerat. Proin tempor faucibus erat, at scelerisque mauris..
```

Comment: The problem is that  "news·.+" expands to include everything following the .+, and so removes the second paragraph. If instead you write "news·.+\n" it will stop at the linebreak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pattern <- "(?<=[[:space:]])(news\\·.{1,})(?=[[:space:]])"
gsub(pattern, "---", text, perl = T)
```

It captures only "news·" that start after a line break, space, or tab, and replace everything until a new line break, space, or tab.